# View won't update in dialog after creation

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Surely a simple question to ask but I've tried for hours and I can't seem to get the problem !

I have a *DialogFragment* which contains a

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/interval_input_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/time_interval_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the listener set on this AutoCompleteView

```
binding.untilInput.onItemClickListener =
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        binding.numberLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        binding.numberLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        binding.numberLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
            }
```

While number layout is just a linear layout like this

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/number_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="For number of events"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

At first the listener wasn't being called so I set it like this instead of directly calling the function setOnItemClickListener (don't know why that wasn't working) , Now the listener is being called , I even put a breakpoint and debugged it and its setting visibility but its not taking any effect and it does not cause any error so I can't seem to get the problem here

Comment: Any actions with binding won't work inside the listener , even if I specify another function to be called , it won't work with binding but binding is not the problem ! its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Using a *DialogFragment* I inflated the view layout with the use of databinding in the method *OnCreateView* & then in *OnViewCreated* I worked with my view and caused changes to UI and set listeners to it and again cause changes to UI
in *OnCreateDialog* I called both of these methods *onCreateView* (to get the view and set it to dialog) and *onViewCreated* to setup the view

I tried to find the view using *findViewById* just to ensure if the databinding was working fine and it was working fine but visibility still won't change and the view won't update !
I still have't gotten to the root of the problem but it seems you have to store the view inside a variable so you don't lose a reference to it when *onClickListener* is called and in my opinion just when the onClickListener is called getting the view from the binding becomes invalid and it should but the small problem is that I am not calling *onDestroy* to make the binding null because the binding was invalid at that time !

Now I am just storing a refrence to binding like this

```
 val myvar = binding.monthLayout
```

and I am capturing the value of myvar inside the *onClickListener* rather than using the binding